# How to get query data using Firebase Firestore?

Tags: java, android, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

```
Query query = mTournamentColRef.whereEqualTo("author", user.getUid());
```

I want to get the id of the Document inside `mTournamentColRef`, but could not find anything in the [Firebase documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/queries) talking about what to do with the query and how to get its data.

Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How to get query data using firebase firestore?

Simply, use a `get()` call!

```
query.get().addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<QuerySnapshot>() {
    @Override
    public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<QuerySnapshot> task) {
        if (task.isSuccessful()) {
            for (QueryDocumentSnapshot document : task.getResult()) {
                Log.d("TAG", "Document Id: " + document.getId());
            }
        }
    }
});
```

There is no need to use `addSnapshotListener` unless you need to get the data in real-time. If you only need to get it and not listen for changes, just use the `get()` method.

Comment: What would you write instead of  **//Get data** to get the Id of a matching document?

Answer (score 1):

You can use data snapshot to get data from query or if you are using Firestore Recycler Adapter you can directly pass the query to the constructor. Here is the code to get specific data:-

```
Query query = mTournamentColRef.whereEqualTo("author", user.getUid());
            query.addSnapshotListener(new EventListener<QuerySnapshot>() {
                @Override
                public void onEvent(QuerySnapshot queryDocumentSnapshots, FirebaseFirestoreException e)
                {
                    for (DocumentSnapshot doc : queryDocumentSnapshots)
                    {
                        Tournament tp = doc.toObject(Tournament.class);
                    }
                }
            });
```

Comment: How would I be able to get the documents (tournaments) id? (btw thanks for your help)

Answer (score 0):

You can get document I'd by
dicumentsnapshot.getId()